# faster insertion to oracle

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

There is a view on sql server host which has about 100 columns and every 4 hours about 40000 new records are inserted into it.
I have written a java application using netbeans that first reads data from SQL Server host and inserts it into an Oracle database table on a different host.

Reading time is short and never exceeds that 20 seconds but insertion takes sometimes more that 10 minutes!
I can not use batches because I need to continue insertion if an exception occurs but if I use batch it will terminates after first exception.

How can I make the process faster?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't use batches because if an exception occurs in one of the batches, it will stop inserting? Wouldn't it terminate after the first exception during the insert anyway if you weren't using batches?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I am using try and catch for handling exceptions but I searched a lot they do not work for batches

Comment: Could you post a summarized version of how you're performing the insert? Not sure why you can't log/handle the exception for one batch and then move onto the next one

Comment: You need to figure out why the inserts are taking so long. Most likely some constraints on the table...

Comment: It takes so long because I'm guessing you are inserting records line by line, especially if you are using try catch. All you can do is optimise your code. If you were to analyse the oracle server you'd find its 'waiting for client' all the time, not waiting for database. You can make the process faster by using a 'proper' integration tool like SSIS or whatever Oracle is selling nowadays.

Comment: Are you using JDBC? Would it be more time-consuming to ensure that the data is error-free before you do the inserts?

Comment: Can you use batches with DML error logging?  For example: http://venzi.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/loading-data-fast-dml-error-logging-performance/

Answer (score 1):

You can use bulk processing easily in Oracle. Just SAVE the exceptions. When your bulk operation completes and there was at least 1 exception, an exception is raised giving you the opportunity to handle them.

For an explanation and an example see [Morgans Library](http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html) Scroll down to exceptions.